# error: "No whitelist configured, no code coverage will be generated" occur only in Netbeans not in cmd while trying to run PHPUnit code-coverage

Tags: netbeans

In Netbeans I try to code-coverage PHPUnit in Symfony2.8 project, but it throws error:

```
"C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\bin\phpunit.bat" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--coverage-clover" "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-coverage.xml" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--" "--run=C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\src\TreningBundle\Tests\Utils\CalculatorTest.php"
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Error:         No whitelist configured, no code coverage will be generated

................I                                                17 / 17 (100%)

Time: 531 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 17, Assertions: 16, Incomplete: 1.
Done.
```

But i have Symfony default app\phpunit.xml.dist with `<whitelist>` defined :

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <!--
            <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
        -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

But in windows console command
`phpunit -c app/ src/TreningBundle/ --coverage-html=cov/` works great, generate coverage.

I got:
Symfony2.8, PHPUnit5.3.4, Netbeans 8.1